# HTML Set the height of the link element into its background

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, height

I would like to ask for help because I could not set the height of the link element (HOME,GAMES,ANIMALS,LOGOUT). The html code:

```
    echo"<div id=\"navigation_bar\">";
echo"<ul>";
echo" <li id=\"home\"><a href=\"animal_home.php\" >HOME</a></li>";
echo" <li id=\"laro\"><a href=\"animal_laro.php\">GAMES</a></li>";
echo" <li id=\"aralin\"><a href=\"animals.php\">ANIMALS</a></li>";
echo" <li id=\"logout\"><a href=\"animal_logout.php\">LOGOUT</a></li>";
echo"</ul>";
echo"</div>";
```

While this is the css:

```
 #navigation_bar ul {
display:block;
float:left;
width:800px;
height:50px;
background:url(images/animal_home_nav.png) no-repeat center;
list-style:none;
}



#navigation_bar ul li  {
display:block;
float:left;
height:50px;
}

  #home{
width:190px;
}


#aralin {
width:220px;
}


#laro {
width:161px;
}

  #logout{
width:200px;    
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking, please clarify your question

Comment: Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - single quoted, heredoc and nowdoc syntax would have saved you escaping and there are several ways to echo multiline strings more easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Add this css in your css file

```
#navigation_bar ul li a{
display:block;
height:100%;
width:100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your css, you should be able to put any dimensions you want on the a tags:

```
#navigation-bar ul li a {
    display:block;
    height:100%; /* or whatever height value you want to use */
}
```

Your issue is that a tags are inline elements and you can only set dimensions on block elements. So if you have dimensions set to your li's (which are block elements) and set a tags to display:block; with width:100%; and height:100%;, they will fill the entire inside of the li.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Love Trivedi must have posted while I was still writing mine :P.